# Build swing program using gradle with kotlin plugin, need -include-runtime

Tags: swing, gradle, kotlin

How to put -include-runtime in build.gradle for kotlin swing program.

Background:

```
- buntu 18.04 64-bit
- OpenJDK 11.0.1
- kotlin 1.3.10
- gradle 5.0
- Swing example borrowed from http://zetcode.com/kotlin/swing/
```

Compile:

```
kotlinc KotlinSwingSimpleEx.kt -include-runtime -d swing.jar
```

Run and Worked:

```
java -jar swing.jar
```

Run and Worked:

```
kotlin -classpath swing.jar com.zetcode.KotlinSwingSimpleExKt
```

However, the followings not work:

```
"gradle build" or "gradle compileKotlin"
```

Run, but not work:

```
java -jar build/libs/swing.jar
```

Error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/swing.jar
```

Run with kotlin got the same error.

Try the followings, but not work (forgot where they come from) (could build, but same error):

Case1: add to build.gradle (something like the following, but not sure)

```
compileKotlin {
  compileOptions.includeRuntime = true
}
```

Case 2: add to build.gradle (something like the following, but not sure)

```
compileOptions {
  freeCompilerArgs = ['-include-runtime']
}
```

Code:

```
// build.gradle
apply plugin: "kotlin"

  buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

A window should be shown. Please help.